# Visa IO error when taking too much data from instrument

Tags: python, pyvisa

I am trying to take data points from an Anto AQ6317C OSA. I have written a script that will take the power and wavelength of the spectrum. It works fine but when I increase the number of data points it gives a visa IO error.

It is an old instrument and gives the data as a string which I convert to a list afterwords. Is there a solution to increase the number of data points without this error arising?

`OSA.write("LDATA")`
`spectrum = OSA.read()` - error appears here when there is too many points.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could it be a timing issue? Did you try a `sleep` between `write` and `read`?